# Why requests throw ConnectionError instead of ReadTimeout in HTTPAdapter?

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm using `requests.adapters.HTTPAdapter` to retry requests in my python3 scripts. And I found that when a request times out, it will throw a `ConnectionError` instead of a `ReadTimeout`.

I'm using python3.7.4 and requests==2.22.0.

And [requests#2392](https://github.com/psf/requests/issues/2392) may be helpful, but I'm not sure are they the same things.

```
import requests
from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter

# request1
try:
    requests.get('http://httpbin.org/delay/2', timeout=1)
except requests.ReadTimeout as e:
    print('request1', e)


s = requests.Session()
s.mount('http://', HTTPAdapter(max_retries=1))

# request2
try:
    s.get('http://httpbin.org/delay/2', timeout=1)
except requests.ReadTimeout as e:
    print('this line will not be printed')
except requests.ConnectionError as e:
    print('request2', e)

# request3
try:
    s.get('http://github.com:88', timeout=1)
except requests.ConnectTimeout as e:
    print('request3', e)

s.close()
```

Here is the output:

```
request1 HTTPConnectionPool(host='httpbin.org', port=80): Read timed out. (read timeout=1)
request2 HTTPConnectionPool(host='httpbin.org', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /delay/2 (Caused by ReadTimeoutError("HTTPConnectionPool(host='httpbin.org', port=80): Read timed out. (read timeout=1)"))
request3 HTTPConnectionPool(host='github.com', port=88): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x10d1a6c10>, 'Connection to github.com timed out. (connect timeout=1)'))
```

In request2, I expect `ReadTimeout` can catch the exception, not `ConnectionError`.

So could anyone tell me why?

Answer (score 0):

Is 'port=88' correct in request 3? All others are port=80.

---

```
# request3
try:
    s.get('http://github.com:88', timeout=1)
except requests.ConnectTimeout as e:
    print('request3', e)
```

---

I did a 'verbose' curl to that url and I get a timeout.

---

curl --url "http://github.com:88" --verbose

---

- Rebuilt URL to: http://github.com:88/

  ---
- Trying 140.82.113.3...

  ---
- TCP_NODELAY set

  ---
- connect to 140.82.113.3 port 88 failed: Timed out

  ---
- Failed to connect to github.com port 88: Timed out

  ---
- Closing connection 0

  ---

curl: (7) Failed to connect to github.com port 88: Timed out

---

---

Same call but port 80 is quick and connects

---

curl --url "http://github.com:80" --verbose

---

- Rebuilt URL to: http://github.com:80/

  ---
- Trying 192.30.253.113...

  ---
- TCP_NODELAY set

  ---
- Connected to github.com (192.30.253.113) port 80 (#0)

  ---

> GET / HTTP/1.1
>
> ---
>
> Host: github.com
>
> ---
>
> User-Agent: curl/7.55.1
>
> ---
>
> Accept: */*
>
> ---

>

---

< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently

---

< Content-length: 0

---

< Location: https://github.com/

---

<

---

Connection #0 to host github.com left intact

Comment: It's correct, I use port=88 to raise a ConnectTimeout on purpose. As a contrast, request3 can raise correct ConnectTimeout but request2 cannot raise ReadTimeout.

Comment: ?I'm confused then, I see "Caused by ReadTimeoutError" in the error for request 2. Am I reading your errors correctly? Maybe set the timeout to timeout=0.00001 or something very small. Github port 80 will be a powerful server.

Comment: Actually we can just ignore the request 3... And focus on why request 2 cannot raise a ReadTimeout error :)

Comment: you need to add 'Error' to your code:change ReadTimeout to ReadTimeoutError.